# Azure devops agent pool - interactive process

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have to stand up a azure pipeline agent for running UI tests that runs "As an interactive process" instead of "As a service". Servers running UI Tests are already prepped for self logon and always on. Can i install the agent on the same server as where the tests are being run?

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question. The easiest way to answer it is to try it. Can you install it? Yes, of course. Will it work? No idea. Try it.

Comment: I agree. Just that if anyone has already tried the scenario and if there are any specific inputs then it would be helpful that's all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have checked [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/ui-testing-considerations?view=azure-devops&tabs=mstest) about how to configure the self hosted agent to run UI test.

I have installed an agent on VM and i can run UI test successfully on the VM.

If UI test can run on the machine where the agent is installed, I think it can also run on the server that runs the UI test, if the agent is installed on the server.

Comment: Thank you. I am running to error with certs, it seems to be running fine when run "as service" but errors out when run as "interactive process" 
Error MSB3325: Cannot import the following key file: C:\cert.pfx. The key file may be password protected. To correct this, try to import the certificate again or manually install the certificate to the Strong Name CSP with the following key container name: VS_KEY_B5EC6A9
The cert is already installed, not sure if its because of how agent is being run

Comment: please have a try to run `sn -i <KeyFile> <ContainerName>` to install key pair into the named container. sn.exe can be found in this place `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools`

Comment: Hi @suprasad havenot heard from you since last update? Please let me know how did it go? We can discuss it to work it out together.

Comment: Hi, @levi lu-msft Thank you the install part works. even though it complains it cannot find the cert when i try to install it errors out that the cert is already there so i tried delete and reinstall it worked. but looks like i probably have to do this every time the pipeline is executed. it looks like either the cert location or some other value keeps missing and i get same error.